# Removing spacing from table cells

Tags: css

I have a dynamic table that I'm customizing with CSS. For some reason it looks like my space restrictions for table cells is partially working as denoted in the picture. I am confused as to why some cells are using too much space, yet others use just enough. I don't understand why "NewsSlider2, Reports, and RSS Feeds" appear to have extra padding. Any idea what is causing this to happen?

CSS:

```css
.pindexAttr table {border:1px solid black; table-layout:fixed; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%}
.pindexAttr td {width:10px; line-height:9px; border:1px solid black;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhZfn/)

Comment: Are you asking why NewsSlider2, Reports, and RSS Feeds seem to have extra padding on the top/bottom?

Comment: @Quentin - accepted answer to the question you posted as a dupe says to use `border-collapse:collapse;` which this user is already doing.

Comment: @andi, Yep, I don't understand why "NewsSlider2, Reports, and RSS Feeds" appear to have extra padding.

Comment: can you post your HTML as well?  or create a fiddle?

Comment: @andi, I've created a fiddle with the html and css.

Comment: Both the HTML and CSS are invalid in your fiddle. Please take a moment and correct it.

Comment: the supplied code have a bunch of unnclosed div tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this on your css overall table:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/mhZfn/1/)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you only need to change  `.pindexAttr table{}` table  to `table.pindexAttr{}`

### [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/snjfs/)

Comment: Just tried this and now my table looks like a blank checkered-board. lol

Comment: What's the problem then , spacing are demoved,just remove padding:10px; that i added

Comment: @acstack we cannot solve this problem for you unless you show us the html as well. Because that may be the real issue.

Comment: @FaceOfJock, See how your demo has the spacing above and below "HAHA.." - I want to remove the spacing so there is only <content> <super small space> <content> <repeat>

Comment: @acstack try to add height to your td's,for example 30px 
`.pindexAttr td {height:30px;width:10px; line-height:9px; border:1px solid black;}
`

Comment: @LoganMurphy, I've added the source and css to jsfiddle.

Comment: @acstack i added height to cells , http://jsfiddle.net/uuxqC/

Comment: This is the right answer. You was specifying a table descendant of an element with class pindexAttr, that was not right. +1